# SQL command for getting average marks

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table marks part of a school database containing the following columns

- **Student_id**: Storing the id of the student
- **Course**: Storing the name of the course
- **Marks**: Storing the marks obtained by the student in the particular course

Write a query to determine the average marks obtained by students. Order the results in the descending order of average marks. In case the average marks are same for two students, student with a lower student_id should appear first.

The output should be of the form

```
|Student_id|avg(marks)|
```

My query:

```
SELECT Student_id, avg(Marks) FROM Marks ORDER BY Student_id DESC
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here? SQL is new for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using below query:

```
SELECT Student_id,
       avg(Marks) AS avg_marks
FROM Marks
GROUP BY Student_id DESC
ORDER BY avg_marks DESC, student_id
```

*Can you elaborate your question providing proper schema, so that we can provide a better solution?*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `GROUP BY Student_id` and `COUNT` each student individually as the denominator in order to determine the average value :

```
SELECT Student_id, 
       SUM(marks) / (SELECT COUNT(Student_id) 
                       FROM Marks 
                      WHERE Student_id = m.Student_id) AS avg_marks
  FROM Marks m 
 GROUP BY Student_id
 ORDER BY avg_marks DESC
```

*P.S.: I didn't understand why you mentioned about the other tables without defining their schema.*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Student_id,
      avg(Marks) AS avg_marks
FROM Marks
GROUP BY Student_id 
ORDER BY avg_marks DESC;`
```

Comment: It should also be sorted by `Student_id ASC`

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_id, avg(marks)
from marks
group by student_id
order by avg(marks) desc, student_id ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).